# Return string with pathvariable to another controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

My main problem here is returning a string with a pathvariable value from one controller to another.

See here:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/profile/{location}")
public ModelAndView profile(@PathVariable("location") String location) throws Exception {
    return new ModelAndView("profile", "*", *);
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/records", method = "RequestMethod.POST") 
public String inRecords(@Valid User user, BindingResult result) {
    if(result.hasErrors()) {
        return "profile/system";  
    }
    else {
        .....
        return "somewhere";
    }
}
```

My problem here is the **return "profile/system"** going to **WEB-INF/views/profile/system.jsp**. Am I doing anything wrong with **@PathVariable** or with the return statement itself?

Any suggestions?

Comment: Look into redirect attributes.

Comment: tried it just now, but errors still won't show.

Comment: The errors don't just show up on their own. It depends how you use them.

Comment: I have a <c:if> for errors to show up when there are any, and since it redirected to the profile/system page, there should be. But the <c:if> result shows that there were no errors? Am I making sense? Pardon me, and thank you.

Comment: I have no idea how you are using either `BindingResult` or `RedirectAttributes`, so I can't help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you dont try something like this.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/records", method = "RequestMethod.POST") 
public void inRecords(@Valid User user, HttpServletResponse response) {
    if(result.hasErrors()) {
        response.sendRedirect("/YourApp/profile/system")
    }
```

I think ModelAndView is taking the returned String and try to run ViewResolver that try to get the jso, avoid that calling or redirecting the request directly to the needed endpoint.

Or If you want to keep modelAndView use this

```
return new ModelAndView("redirect:/profile/system");
```

Comment: Thank you :) ! I figured it out just a while ago, even though its bad practice, I just copied the contents of ModelAndView profile under the result.hasErrors() and used return new ModelAndView("profile", "*", *).